# Deploying data-tier applications using inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, setup-deployment, data-tier-applications, dacpac

i need help.
There is a data-tier application .dacpac which is need to be deployed at another user's computers using inno setup. Script creates SQL Server instance at target machine and then the data-tier application must be deployed. I think it is possible to use sqlpackage.exe, but i must include all dependency ddls in my installation exe. Is there any another ways to deploy data-tier application?

Comment: Inno can do whatever you tell it to do, but will need the SQL server installer and something to communicate with it. This isn't included with Inno so you'll need to find one suitable for your needs.

Comment: That's right and i could deploy the database from sql-script using sqlcmd.exe which is free to distribute. Question is - can i distribute sqlpackage.exe and all of its dependencies?

Comment: With Inno yes, just include it in the setup and use `ExtractTemporaryFile()`. Whether you can legally depends on the licence of the package.